# How can i sort the table in a application using JQuery or Js and bring back results based on a column that contains images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a project and i try to figure out a way to short a table that will bring back results based on a column that contains only images. 
To be more exact :

My column's field name is Logos and contains the code below:

```
<table> 
 <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><img alt="Logo 1" src="logos/logo-1.png" /></td>
        <td><img alt="Logo 2" src="logos/logo-2.png" /></td>
        <td><img alt="Logo 3" src="logos/logo-3.png" /></td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

On top of that the html selection is:

```
<select id="kt_form_type" class="form-control bootstrap-select">

<option value="">All</option>
<option value="Logo 1">Logo 2</option>
<option value="Logo 2">Logo 3</option>
<option value="Logo 3">Logo 3</option>

</select>
```

I tried this

```
$('#kt_form_type').on('change', function () {
  datatable.search($(this).val().toLowerCase(), 'Logos');
   });
```

But the results where not even close to what i try to achieve.

Comment: For starters take a look at JavaScripts "[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)"a function.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but helpful: https://www.sitepoint.com/12-amazing-jquery-tables/

Comment: Are you using datatable.js library?

Comment: @HansC.FelixRamos I am using this template https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/demo5/crud/metronic-datatable/base/html-table.html

Comment: @PedroLobito I am going to check it out.

Comment: Smart choice ;)